# Looking for an implementation of an abstract method

Tags: java, class, arraylist, abstract-methods

I need to make a programm which is like a rally, theres 2 types of vehicles, motorcycle and cars, two types of motorcycle, with and without sidecar, the thing is that I need to verify if there is just a motorcycle in an array list, I mean, two wheels vehicle. That verification should be done in a method called `esDe2Ruedas()`, which is called by an abstract overrided method called `check()` that should be the one that verifies if a group of vehicles from an array are able to run in the rally, if its true all the elements of the array must be from the same type.

Here is the code

this is how the program arrays the vehicles

```
GrandPrix gp1 = new GrandPrix();
    gp1.agregar(v1);
    //gp1.mostrar(v1);
    gp1.agregar(v2);
    System.out.println(gp1.check());

    GrandPrix gp2 = new GrandPrix();
    gp2.agregar(vt1);
    gp2.agregar(vt2);
    gp2.agregar(m2);
    System.out.println(gp2.check());

    GrandPrix gp3 = new GrandPrix();
    gp3.agregar(vt1);
    gp3.agregar(vt2);
    gp3.agregar(m1);
    System.out.println(gp3.check());

    GrandPrix gp4 = new GrandPrix();
    gp4.agregar(m1);
    gp4.agregar(m2);
    System.out.println(gp4.check());
```

This is the class that is using

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class GrandPrix extends Rally{
        
        ArrayList<Vehiculo> ve = new ArrayList<Vehiculo>();
    
        public void agregar(Vehiculo v) {
            ve.add(v);
        }
    
        public void agregar(Carro c) {
            ve.add(c);
        }
    
        public void agregar(Moto m) {
            ve.add(m);
        }
    
        @Override
        boolean check() {// HERE I VERIFY IF THE VEHICLES ARE COMPATIBLE
            return false;
        }
    
    }
```

This is the class where everything goes on

```
public class Vehiculo {
    
    private String Nombre;
    private double velocidad_max;
    private int peso;
    private int comb;
    
    public Vehiculo() {
        setNombre("Anónimo");
        setVel(130);
        setPeso(1000);
        setComb(0);
    }
    
    public Vehiculo(String string, double d, int i, int j) {
        setNombre(string);
        setVel(d);
        setPeso(i);
        setComb(j);
    }

    double rendimiento() {
        return velocidad_max/peso;
    }

    public boolean mejor(Vehiculo otroVehiculo) {
        return rendimiento()>otroVehiculo.rendimiento();
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return getNombre()+"-> Velocidad máxima = "+getVel()+" km/h, Peso = "+getPeso()+" kg";
    }
    
    /**************************************
    ---------SET And GET Nombre------------
    ***************************************/
    
    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nuevoNombre) {
        this.Nombre=nuevoNombre;
    }
    
    /**************************************
    ---------SET And GET velocidad_max------------
    ***************************************/
    
    public double getVel() {
        return velocidad_max;
    }
    public void setVel(double nuevaVel) {
        this.velocidad_max=nuevaVel;
    }
    
    /**************************************
    ---------SET And GET peso------------
    ***************************************/
    
    public double getPeso() {
        return peso;
    }
    public void setPeso(int nuevoPeso) {
        this.peso=nuevoPeso;
    }

    /**************************************
    ---------SET And GET comb------------
    ***************************************/
    
    public int getComb() {
        return comb;
    }

    public void setComb(int comb) {
        this.comb = comb;
    }
    
    boolean esDe2Ruedas() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

This is the class of motorcycles, which is in theory the same as the car's class, without sidecar thing

```
public class Moto extends Vehiculo{
    
    private boolean sidecar;
    public Moto(String string, double d, int i, int j) {
        setNombre(string);
        setVel(d);
        setPeso(i);
        setComb(j);
        setSidecar(false);
        
    }
    public Moto(String string, double d, int i, int j, boolean b) {
        setNombre(string);
        setVel(d);
        setPeso(i);
        setComb(j);
        setSidecar(b);
        esDe2Ruedas(false);
    }

    public String toString() {
        String str = null;
        if(isSidecar())
            str =super.toString()+", Moto, con sidecar";
        else
            str =super.toString()+", Moto";
        return str;
    }
    public boolean isSidecar() {
        return sidecar;
    }
    public void setSidecar(boolean sidecar) {
        this.sidecar = sidecar;
    }
```

Comment: I'm new on this and I'm not looking for someone to make me the code, just some help about how can I verify if a vehicle has two wheels through the esDe2Ruedas() method

Comment: I dont see the Rally class. But on the Motorcycle class can you just override esDe2Ruedas()to return true ? and in the GrandPrix class, check() method to a if else statement with if class Motorcycle return true or false accordingly to what you want ? Not sure if I understood what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you presented is what is given. If you came up with the design it is ok, but I believe it could be improved. Anyway, I try to respond to what I believe was your question straight away.

`Vehiculo` is the super type of `Moto` (which can have a side car and becomes 3 wheeler).

`Vehiculo` has a method `esDe2Ruedas`, which returns false.

`Moto` inherits that method <-- this is wrong, it should override it and, depending on side car, return the expected boolean value.

In the check method you can now distinguish between `Moto` and "`Moto` with sidecar" by using that method.